# Absurd result when attempting to show that the intersection of two subspaces is the zero vector

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

For two subspaces $U,W = \mathbb{R^2}$ where $U=\operatorname{span}(1,1)$ and $W=\operatorname{span}(2,1)$, I'm trying to show that $U\cap W$ is the zero vector $\{\mathbf{0}\}$. My proof so far:

Let $x\in U\cap W$, then $x\in U$ and $x\in W$. Because $U=\operatorname{span}(1,1)$, then $x=a(1,1)$. Likewise because $W=\operatorname{span}(2,1)$, then $x=b(2,1)$. Therefore $x=a(1,1)=b(2,1)$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. So $(a,a)=(2b,b)$ therefore $a=2b$ and $a=b$. But this would imply $1=2$.

Did I do something wrong? Is the absurd result $1=2$ enough to conclude that $U\cap W=\{\mathbf{0}\}$?

Comment: This would imply $1=2$ *if $a$ and $b$ are not zero*. This means that they must be necessarily zero. in other words, in the intersection there is only the zero vector.

Comment: @Crostul Oh ok. Makes sense. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

"... this would imply 1=2." is incorrect.

The equations
$$
a=2b,\quad a=b
$$
imply that $a=b=0$.